# How to identify and list octopus merges using git log?

Tags: git, merge, git-log

Is there any way to **list** all **octopus** **merges** in a git repository using git commands (e.g. git log ...)?

Comment: A) Why the bold text (expecially the word "list"). B) Does it have to be `git log` or is any other combination of git tools OK?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Anything works! I meant not using any external library! I want to a list of all octopus merges, not other merges.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit selectors in `git log` and `git rev-list` (these are nearly the same command) include `--min-parents` and `--max-parents`.  An octopus merge is defined as "any merge with three or more parents", hence `--min-parents=3` rejects all but octopus merges.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!